# Jquery dynamic creating HTML divs on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I’m looking for some direction for my problem.

I’ve HTML divs and I want to replicate it when user clicks on span with id plus-1.
This is my **html**

```
<div id = “tab”>
<div class="row">
    <div>
        <select id="ProjectsFolder0FolderId" name="data[ProjectsFolder][0][folder_id]">
            <option value="1">Project Presentation</option>
            <option selected="selected" value="4">Project Root</option>
        </select>                
    </div>
    <div>
        <div>
            <input type="text" required="required" id="ProjectsFolder0Linux" value="xyz"  name="data[ProjectsFolder][0][linux]">
        </div>           
    </div>
    <div id="plus-1" >
                <span>
                    Click here
                </span>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

**Jquery**

```
$(document).on('click', '#plus-1' , function() {
        var html = "<div class=\"row\" >"
                  ???
                 + "</div>";
    $('#tab').append(html);

        });
```

It is appending above html defined in jquery , but I don’t know how to append entire HTML efficiently as required above on each click.

Comment: Do you want to copy your 'plus-1' button as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Demo [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sethuramanP/8MVcR/2/)

**Jquery**

```
 $(document).on('click', '#plus-1' , function() {   
        var html = $(this).parent().clone();
        html.find('#plus-1').attr('id','plus-'+($('#tab').find('.row').length+1));
        $('#tab').append(html);
 });
```

Comment: `select` and `input` inside cloned element will have the same ids and names with your code. Also, your cloned element plus button won't trigger anything, since its id will be different, and delegated event is only for `plus-1`

Answer (score 1):

Made a jsfiddle for you - http://jsfiddle.net/23GCn/. You also have an error in your html, you need to use correct parenthesis on `<div id="tab">`

```
jQuery(function($){
   var count = 1;
   $(document).on("click", "[id^='plus']", function(){             
       newBlock = $(this).parents(".row").clone();
       count += 1;

       // change id of Plus button
       newBlock.find("[id^='plus']").attr("id", "plus-"+count);

       // Change id and name of select box
       newBlock.find("select")
           .attr("id", "ProjectsFolder"+count+"FolderId")
           .attr("name", "data[ProjectsFolder]["+count+"][folder_id]");

       // Same for input
       newBlock.find("input[type='text']")
           .attr("id", "ProjectsFolder"+count+"Linux")
           .attr("name", "data[ProjectsFolder]["+count+"][linux]");

      // append new element to your tab
      $("#tab").append(newBlock);
   });    
});
```

Note that `[id^='plus']` type selectors are very inefficient, means, slow. Consider using classes instead of ids, this way you avoid all of the code required to change ids, since you can't have elements with same id on your page obviously.

Comment: Yes. `$(this)` refers to clicked element. `parents("row")` is its `<div class="row">` parent. And the `clone()` is a jQuery function for creating a copy of a set of matched elements. For `[id^='plus']` it means select all elements, whose `id` attribute starts with `'plus'`

Comment: @Андрей Почекуев `new` is a reserved word.

Comment: You mean the one you accepted. Please notice, that it produces invalid HTML, which i stated in my comment.